# Verify that method is called within Action

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am practicing unit-testing a lot of these days, so bear with me if I fail to understand some basics.

Having these simple abstractions:

```
public interface ITaskFactory
{
    void StartTask(Action action);
}

internal sealed class TaskFactory : ITaskFactory
{
    public void StartTask(Action action)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(action);
    }
}
```

And this class to test (simplified to this case):

```
internal sealed class TriggerEventDecorator<TEvent> : ITriggerEvent<TEvent> where TEvent : IEvent
{
    private readonly ITaskFactory _taskFactory;
    private readonly Func<ITriggerEvent<TEvent>> _factory;

    public TriggerEventDecorator(ITaskFactory taskFactory, Func<ITriggerEvent<TEvent>> factory)
    {
        _taskFactory = taskFactory;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Trigger(TEvent evt)
    {
        _taskFactory.StartTask(() =>
        {
            _factory().Trigger(evt);
        });
    }
}
```

And my test of this class:

```
public class TriggerEventDecoratorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void CanTriggerEventHandler()
    {
        var evt = new FakeEventWithoutValidation();
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEvent>(evt);

        var decorated = new Mock<ITriggerEvent<FakeEventWithoutValidation>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        decorated.Setup(x => x.Trigger(evt));

        var taskFactory = new Mock<ITaskFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        taskFactory.Setup(factory => factory.StartTask(It.IsAny<Action>()));

        var decorator = new TriggerEventDecorator<FakeEventWithoutValidation>(taskFactory.Object, () => decorated.Object);
        decorator.Trigger(evt);

        taskFactory.Verify(x => x.StartTask(It.IsAny<Action>()), Times.Once);
        decorated.Verify(x => x.Trigger(evt), Times.Once); // This line is not verified
    }
}
```

The line `decorated.Verify(x => x.Trigger(evt), Times.Once);` is not verified, it is never invoked.

How do I test that this is trigged in the `Action` of the `_taskFactory`?

Comment: Generally, when there are more than one Mock in a Unit Test, it means developer is confused and is lost. Here, I think it happened. What are you going to test? If you want to test `TriggerEventDecorator` then why is it mocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't invoke the `Func` method. This is the problem... To do so you'll have to use `Callback` method.

Change the following sertup:

```
taskFactory.Setup(factory => factory.StartTask(It.IsAny<Action>()));
```

To:

```
taskFactory.Setup(factory => factory.StartTask(It.IsAny<Action>()))
           .Callback<Action>((action) => action());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, getting the hang of using the `.Callback(..)` now! Thanks again! :-)